# SSRS count duplicate values only

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Dears ,

My issue is I need to count duplicated values using count expression in ssrs .

All solutions on internet are to count distinct values.
thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOoe5.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can be done but explain how you want to count the duplicates. Do you want to count how many times a value appears?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Do it with SQL query**

```
declare @tb as TABLE ([number] int NULL,    [fruit] [varchar](50) NULL)

INSERT into @tb ([number], [fruit]) VALUES (3, N'apple')
INSERT into @tb ([number], [fruit]) VALUES (4, N'apple')
INSERT into @tb ([number], [fruit]) VALUES (6, N'banana')
INSERT into @tb ([number], [fruit]) VALUES (5, N'orange')
INSERT into @tb ([number], [fruit]) VALUES (7, N'orange')
INSERT into @tb ([number], [fruit]) VALUES (8, N'apple')
INSERT into @tb ([number], [fruit]) VALUES (9, N'banana')

select fruit,count(number) as count from @tb group by fruit
```

-------------------Edited-------------------

**2 . Do in SSRS** 
[image]

[image]

Comment: unlikely my data source and data set from SharePoint so I need to do this through SSRS expression thanks

Comment: If you wanted to do it through SSRS, just use the Grouping

Comment: thanks for answer but this also didn't work my table is custom one Columns group and each field have it's own expression I hope i could upload screen shoot but I can't .. that is why i need to do it by use expression only and I'm stuck on this for a week or so

Comment: So, repeated calls.. any sample raw data? You can simply provide a few line raw data for us to help.